# How do i make discord.js list all the members in a role?

Tags: discord.js

```
if(message.content == `${config.prefix}mods`) {
        const ListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Mods:')
        .setDescription(message.guild.roles.cache.get('813803673703809034').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'));
        message.channel.send(ListEmbed);                    
    }
```

Hey so iam making a command which displays all the members with that role but it only seems to be sending 1 of the mods

Answer (score 0):

```js
await message.guild.roles.fetch();
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == args[0]);
if (!role) return message.channel.send('Role does not exist'); //if role cannot be found by entered ID

let roleMembers = role.members.map(m  => m.user.tag).join('\n');

const ListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Users with \`${role.name}\``)
    .setDescription(roleMembers);
    message.channel.send(ListEmbed);    
};
```

Make sure your command is async, otherwise it will not run the `await message.guild.roles.fetch();` - this fetches all roles in the server to make sure the command works reliably.

In `Discord.jsV12` the `get` method was redacted and `find` was implemented.

Aswell as this, I would highly recommend defining variables to use in embeds and for searching since it is much more easy to error trap.

If you have many members with the role, you will encounter the `maximum character limit` for an embeds description. Simply split the arguments between multiple embeds.